# openCL and VC++ 2010 "front end compiler failed build"

Tags: visual-c++, opencl

I have just begun to learn openCL and coded with VC++ 2010. I have followed this instruction to set up openCL for Visual Studio. Everything is fine except that the paths are a little different for CUDA 5, so I ignored "~\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK\shared\inc".

http://opencl.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=OpenCL%20Tutorials%20-%200&referringTitle=OpenCL%20Tutorials

Then I compiled some very basic examples with only CL/cl.h and they worked fine. However, when I began to include stdio.h, I kept receiving the error "fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found"

Here is an exampe (this code is from openCl in Action)

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define PROGRAM_FILE "matvec.cl"
#define KERNEL_FUNC "matvec_mult"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#ifdef MAC
#include <OpenCL/cl.h>
#else  
#include <CL/cl.h>
#endif


int main() {

   /* Host/device data structures */
   cl_platform_id platform;
   cl_device_id device;
   cl_context context;
   cl_command_queue queue;
   cl_int i, err;

   /* Program/kernel data structures */
   cl_program program;
   FILE *program_handle;
   char *program_buffer, *program_log;
   size_t program_size, log_size;
   cl_kernel kernel;

   /* Data and buffers */
   float mat[16], vec[4], result[4];
   float correct[4] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
   cl_mem mat_buff, vec_buff, res_buff;
   size_t work_units_per_kernel;

   /* Initialize data to be processed by the kernel */
   for(i=0; i<16; i++) {
      mat[i] = i * 2.0f;
   } 
   for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
      vec[i] = i * 3.0f;
      correct[0] += mat[i]    * vec[i];
      correct[1] += mat[i+4]  * vec[i];
      correct[2] += mat[i+8]  * vec[i];
      correct[3] += mat[i+12] * vec[i];      
   }

   /* Identify a platform */
   err = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, NULL);
   if(err < 0) {
      perror("Couldn't find any platforms");
      exit(1);
   }

   /* Access a device */
   err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, 
         &device, NULL);
   if(err < 0) {
      perror("Couldn't find any devices");
      exit(1);
   }

   /* Create the context */
   context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device, NULL, 
         NULL, &err);
   if(err < 0) {
      perror("Couldn't create a context");
      exit(1);   
   }

   /* Read program file and place content into buffer */
   program_handle = fopen(PROGRAM_FILE, "r");
   if(program_handle == NULL) {
      perror("Couldn't find the program file");
      exit(1);   
   }
   fseek(program_handle, 0, SEEK_END);
   program_size = ftell(program_handle);
   rewind(program_handle);
   program_buffer = (char*)malloc(program_size + 1);
   program_buffer[program_size] = '\0';
   fread(program_buffer, sizeof(char), program_size, program_handle);
   fclose(program_handle);

   /* Create program from file */
   program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, 
      (const char**)&program_buffer, &program_size, &err);
   if(err < 0) {
      perror("Couldn't create the program");
      exit(1);   
   }
   free(program_buffer);

   /* Build program */
   **err = clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);**
   if(err < 0) {

      /* Find size of log and print to std output */
      clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, 
            0, NULL, &log_size);
      program_log = (char*) malloc(log_size + 1);
      program_log[log_size] = '\0';
      clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, 
            log_size + 1, program_log, NULL);
      printf("%s\n", program_log);
      free(program_log);
      exit(1);
   }

   /* Create kernel for the mat_vec_mult function */
   kernel = clCreateKernel(program, KERNEL_FUNC, &err);
   if(err < 0) {
      perror("Couldn't create the kernel");
      exit(1);   
   }

   /* Create CL buffers to hold input and output data */
   mat_buff = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | 
      CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(float)*16, mat, &err);
   if(err < 0) {
      perror("Couldn't create a buffer object");
      exit(1);   
   }      
   vec_buff = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | 
      CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(float)*4, vec, NULL);
   res_buff = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, 
      sizeof(float)*4, NULL, NULL);

   /* Create kernel arguments from the CL buffers */
   err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &mat_buff);
   if(err < 0) {
      perror("Couldn't set the kernel argument");
      exit(1);   
   }         
   clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &vec_buff);
   clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &res_buff);

   /* Create a CL command queue for the device*/
   queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device, 0, &err);
   if(err < 0) {
      perror("Couldn't create the command queue");
      exit(1);   
   }

   /* Enqueue the command queue to the device */
   work_units_per_kernel = 4; /* 4 work-units per kernel */ 
   err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &work_units_per_kernel, 
      NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
   if(err < 0) {
      perror("Couldn't enqueue the kernel execution command");
      exit(1);   
   }

   /* Read the result */
   err = clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, res_buff, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float)*4, 
      result, 0, NULL, NULL);
   if(err < 0) {
      perror("Couldn't enqueue the read buffer command");
      exit(1);   
   }

   /* Test the result */
   if((result[0] == correct[0]) && (result[1] == correct[1])
      && (result[2] == correct[2]) && (result[3] == correct[3])) {
      printf("Matrix-vector multiplication successful.\n");
   }
   else {
      printf("Matrix-vector multiplication unsuccessful.\n");
   }

   /* Deallocate resources */
   clReleaseMemObject(mat_buff);
   clReleaseMemObject(vec_buff);
   clReleaseMemObject(res_buff);
   clReleaseKernel(kernel);
   clReleaseCommandQueue(queue);
   clReleaseProgram(program);
   clReleaseContext(context);

   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

the clBuildProgram gave error that it can't find stdio.h.

Also, here are the warnings:

```
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\OpenCL.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\IntelOpenCL32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86\intelocl.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4974_none_50940634bcb759cb\msvcp90.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4974_none_50940634bcb759cb\msvcr90.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\glu32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\Browser Manager\2.5.976.107\{c16c1ccb-7046-4e5c-a2f3-533ad2fec8e8}\mngr.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imagehlp.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvinit.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\profapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\detoured.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\Nvd3d9wrap.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\nvdxgiwrap.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86\clang_compiler.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86\task_executor.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86\tbb.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dbghelp.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86\cpu_device.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\igdrcl32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvcuda.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'cl2.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvcuda.dll'
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvopencl.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nsi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wintrust.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\crypt32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msasn1.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\igdfcl32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'cl2.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\igdfcl32.dll'
The program '[6324] cl2.exe: Native' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

Please show me how to fix that.

Best Regards

Comment: Did your simple examples include stdio.h?  If they compiled, then this is an error propagation.  Otherwise, check your paths.

Comment: Hi, the simple one that worked didnt haven stdio.h. The one I copied here is the very first one that did, and I received the error above.

Comment: remove stdio.h in matvec.cl

Comment: Hi, I forgot to mention, I just copy the code from the source, and the file above is matvec.cl itself. Why need to remove stdio.h in it? Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @JoshVo The file above cannot be matvec.cl, instead it's the host program which compiles the kernel program, matvec.cl. IF the above file IS matvec.cl, then you are completely mistaken by compiling that.